# Convert Ruby Script to Python - Problem with encoding/decoding of bytes

Tags: ruby, python-3.x, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to convert a ruby script to a python script. The script is supposed to read a binary file and convert it to readable strings. The binary file contains some korean symbols. I tried multiple decodings, but none seemed to work. In the end, the data is supposed to be formatted into a table. (Not seen in this code, just mentioned for better understanding)

The ruby script runs fine without any problems at all.

I'm not sure if test file is needed, but I've uploaded it [on Mediafire](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pf2aaswmxt3f2o8/test.bin/file).

Thanks for helping me out! :)

**Ruby Script:**

```
# encoding: utf-8

def columntypes(t)
    case(t)
      when 0
        return 4
      when 1
        return 4
      when 2
        return 4
      when 3
        return 12
      when 4
        return 32
      when 5
        return 128
    end
    return 0
end

  doc = File.open("test.bin", "rb")

  bin = {
    'datasets'=>doc.read(4).unpack("l*")[0],
    'datasetslength'=>doc.read(4).unpack("l*")[0],
    'columns'=>doc.read(4).unpack("l*")[0]
  }

  columns = Array.new
  bin['columns'].times do |i|
    columns << {'name'=>doc.read(32).gsub(/\x00.*/, "").encode('utf-8', 'EUC-KR').strip, 'length'=>columntypes(doc.read(4).unpack("l*")[0])}
  end

  datasets = Array.new
  bin['datasets'].times do |d|
    trash = doc.read(4)
    dataset = Array.new
    columns.each do |c|
      data = doc.read(c['length'])
      puts "#{data}"
      if c['length']!=4 then
        #string
        dataset << data.gsub(/\x00.*/, "").encode('utf-8', 'EUC-KR').chomp
      else
        #float/integer
        dataset << data.unpack("L")[0]
      end
    end
    datasets << dataset
  end
end
```

**Python Script**

```
# encoding: utf-8
import struct
import re

def columntypes(t):
    if t == 0:
        return 4
    elif t == 1:
        return 4
    elif t == 2:
        return 4
    elif t == 3:
        return 12
    elif t == 4:
        return 32
    elif t == 5:
        return 128
    else:
        return 0

doc = open("test.bin", "rb")

b = {
    "datasets": struct.unpack("l", doc.read(4))[0],
    "datasets_length": struct.unpack("l", doc.read(4))[0],
    "columns": struct.unpack("l", doc.read(4))[0],
}

columns = []
for x in range(b["columns"]):
    data = doc.read(32)
    data = re.sub(b"/\x00.*/", b"", data)
    data = data.decode("utf-8")
    name = data.rstrip("\x00")

    columns.append(
        {
            "name": name,
            "length": columntypes(struct.unpack("l", doc.read(4))[0])
        }
    )

datasets = []
for x in range(b["datasets"]):
    trash = doc.read(4)
    dataset = []
    for c in columns:
        data = doc.read(c["length"])

        if c["length"] != 4:
            data = re.sub(b"/\x00.*/", b"", data)
            # Error here
            # Encodings tried: utf-8, euc_kr, cp949
            d = data.decode("utf-8").rstrip("\x00")

            datasets.append(d)

        else:
            datasets.append(struct.unpack("L", data)[0])

doc.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is that you put the slashes that are used as delimiter of the regular expression in ruby, in the python string too, and that breaks the replacement.
change

```
         data = re.sub(b"/\x00.*/", b"", data)
```

to

```
         data = re.sub(b"\x00.*", b"", data)
```

and it should go better.

I also needed to replace the "l" with "i" in the various unpack calls, i'm not totally sure it's normal, but that worked for me.

sample output from "d"

```
ISLAND_00
카디프섬#
カ?ディフ島#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
Cardiff Island#
?迪夫?#
?迪夫島#
ISLAND_01
마그넬 섬#
マグネル島#
```